# how to start a browser with a Google image search query in android

Tags: android, google-search-api, google-image-search

I was wondering how to start a Browser with a Google image search query "search images by text". For example user can select a certain word or phrase and click a button and the activity will start the browser with the Google image search query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Create URL like so:***

```
String URLString = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&q="+TestString;
```

***Launch it like so:***

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URLString));
startActivity(i);
```

***Make sure your TestString is URL Safe***

Comment: Note: the `tbm=isch` is what's need to switch to the Image tab.

Comment: Note 2: For me, just the search query + `tbm` is all that was needed.  Both on Android and Chrome on Mac OSX, it worked with just this `"https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&q=" + searchQueryString`

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add `tbm=isch`

Example:

url: `https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=findSomeImage`